# Spring boot app not running from command prompt but successfully running from STS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created spring boot app. I have used 2.0.0.RELEASE version of spring-boot-starter-parent.

Application is working fine from STS IDE as a> Run as > Spring Boot App

When I am trying to build executable jar and run application from command prompt, I am getting 404 error. I know this is strange issue. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you get a 404 the app is running but no endpoint defined. More informations would be very helpful

Comment: share snippets for your pom.xml and controllers

Comment: Can you add the two commands being used for running the app? One in the IDE and one from the terminal.

Comment: From IDE : > Right Click on project > Run As > Spring Boot App
From command Prompt : > mvn clean package
                                         > java -jar my-app.jar

Comment: This is snippet of POM: 
<build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <executable>true</executable>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
  <finalName>my-app</finalName>
 </build>

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please don't post additional information as comments, edit your question in stead.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks